# What's the best way to quickly count rows between filters in Excel pivot tables?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to count the number of rows between the filters in the pivot table.

For example In the first filter there are `7` lines. In the second filter, `6` lines and so on. Its a lot of data that manually will consume a lot of time. Please advise.

[image]

I tried modifing the parameters but I receive the quantity it repeats, and I need how many are per line individually.

Comment: What you want can be easily achieved if you understand the concept of pivot items and pivot fields. I would recommend giving it a try and share the code that you attempted and we will take it from there.

HINT: **1.** Loop through the PivotFields **2.** Check if it has grand total. **3.** Get the field position. We are concerned with the field at position 1. **4.**  Loop though each PivotItems in the PivotField. **5.** Filter on that Pivot item. **6.** Count the visible rows in the 1st Column. **7.** Adjust the visible rows for PivotFiled and GrandTotal. and you are done :)

Comment: Sorry what I forgot to mention is that my suggestion above involves VBA code. If you are looking for a vba solution then tag your quesiton with VBA tag as well.